# Dedicated home partition and disk allocation

Tags: partitioning, home-directory

I have read numerous arguments - both for and against - a dedicated home partition, but in my case, I feel that the pros outweigh the cons.

I have a 512 GB SSD in my machine running 18.4.4 LTS.

What is the right balance to ensure that I have suitable storage for the root file system, swap, etc. and my home directory?

Right now, my current thinking is to allocate ~100 GB for root, but that's simply based on some suggestions in [this installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/apcs02.html).

**UPDATE:** My application set is mostly office docs, photo and video projects. Once completed, I delete the source files from my local drive.  My home directory is somewhat elastic due to the video projects. My photo library and completed video projects are stored on NAS.

Comment: My `/` (excluding `/home`) is about 22G plus a 20G swap file. So 100G is not unreasonable, perhaps a bit on the generous side.

Comment: @gadgetboy: How many programs of what size do you plan on installing? Will you be storing all your vacation photos in home or on a separate data disk? Will you be downloading a lot of TV shows and Movies? I have a 500GB disk and 400GB is in home.

Comment: I keep /home inside / (root) as I have several installs in 25 or 30GB partitions. When I install a test install I want to have data available, but not change settings in main working install. I have a fair numbers of apps and currently using 8GB in / with /home (but no data). You now do not need swap partition as default is a swap file of 2GB. Only if you want hibernation which normally is not recommended may you need larger swap partition.

Comment: The answer to this question is totally dependent on your personal needs and uses. There is no one "right" answer. I am voting to close this question as answers (if any) will be opinion based.